# Сохранение контента richtextbox в файл rtf

Tags: c#, winforms

Вот мой код. Вроде стандартная процедур,а не выходит.

P.S. `GetRichTextBox()` - функция получения текста из richtextbox'a в дочерней форме `mdi`.

```
if (GetRichTextBox() == null)
    return;

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && sfd.FileName.Length > 0)
{
    GetRichTextBox().SaveFile(sfd.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichNoOleObjs);
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
void SaveTextToRtf(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GetRichTextBox() == null)
        return;

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && sfd.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
        {
            using(File.Create(sfd.FileName));
                GetRichTextBox().SaveFile(sfd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        }
        else
        {
            GetRichTextBox().SaveFile(sfd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно, что у Вас нет прав на запись файла по указанному пути. Также следует проверить, есть ли файл, если нет - то создать, как указано в примере.